# Java Compile time non polymorphism

Tags: java, compilation, polymorphism, overloading

In the code below I get a compiler error at b.printname();. As I understand it the error is to do with the fact that the compiler is effectively operating in a non polymorphic way( i.e. the compiler is essentially only choosing to look at the left side of the operand and therefore b is a Question). Since b is of type Question and since Question does not have a no-args printName method you get a compilation error. Is that correct?
Now assuming that is correct, my question is why? Surely the compiler should know that Question b is referring to an object that does in fact support the  no-args printName method? E.g. if you look at how the compiler behaves in terms of casting there are examples where the compiler, for lack of a better word, acts polymorphicly or to put it a different way the compiler knows what's going on in terms of the right hand side of the operand and acts upon that knowledge. An example would be if an interface type refers to an object that implements the interface, then the compiler looks at the right hand side of the statement (i.e. the object that implements the interface) and decides no cast is required. So why doesn't the compiler act that way here, why doesn't it look and see that the object in question is actually a Blue and that a Blue does indeed support the no-arg method printName?

```
public class Polymorf3 {



     public static void main(String[] args){
         Polymorf3 me = new Polymorf3();
         me.doStuff();
     }

     public void doStuff() {
         Bat a = new Bat();
         Question b = new Blue();
         //a.printName();  
         a.printName(a.name);
         b.printName(); // Compiler Error:Required String Found no args
     }
     abstract class Question {
         String name="Question_name";
           public void printName(String name){ System.out.println(name);}
     }
     class Bat extends Question {
         String name = "Bat_Bruce";
         //public void printName(){ System.out.println(name);}

     }
     class Blue extends Question {
         String name = "Clark";
         public void printName() {System.out.println(name);}
     }
}
```

Comment: Since here `b` contains the reference of `Question` class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though `b` is of type `Blue`, since you declared it as `Question b = new Blue();`, the compiler treats it as type `Question`, and thus that's the only interface available to it without an explicit cast:

```
((Blue)b).printName();
```

Alternatively, you can declare it as `Blue b = new Blue();` and `b.printName();` will not throw a compile time error.

Essentially what's happening here is that you're declaring your new variable `b` at a higher level of abstraction, so the only `printName` method available to `b` is the one in the higher level of abstraction, the one with the args.

**Edit:**

OP asked why the compiler treats `b` as a `Question` even though it's initialized as `Blue`. Consider the following:

```
Question q = new Blue();
// ... some other code...
q = new Bat(); // Valid!!
q.printName("some string");
```

Now consider that tomorrow, some other developer comes in and changes it to the following:

```
Blue q = new Blue();
// ... some other code...
q = new Bat(); // Invalid!! Compiler error
q.printName("some string");
```

Declaring a variable at the highest level of abstraction required for your operation means you can later change the implementation more easily and without affecting all the rest of your code. Thus, it should be clear why the Java compiler is treating `b` as a `Question`. It's because `b` can, at any time, become an instance of `Blue` or `Bat`, so treating it as the implementation (`Blue` or `Bat`) would violate the contract of the `Question` interface by allowing some other non-arg `getName` method.

Comment: Sorry I don't think my question was clear. I understand the logic. I understand that when you declare b as a Question then it's treated like a Question and in this case Question does not support the requested method. However, my question concerns the Java compiler. Why doesn't the compiler act on the information it has? i.e. surely it knows that b is in fact a Blue and it knows that Blue supports the requested method.

Comment: Thanks you that certainly answers my question. I'd up vote you if I could but my reputation has been destroyed after posing this question. :(

Comment: Glad I could help :-)

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have misunderstood what polymorphism means. It means that you can treat an instance of the derived class as if it was an instance of the base class. That includes not calling methods on it that the base class doesn't provide. The variable type informs what methods you can call, and the instantiation type determines what implementations of those methods are run.

By putting your `Blue` instance in a `Question` variable, you are asking to treat it like a `Question`. If you wanted to call methods on your `Question` variable that are not provided by the `Question` class, then why have it be a `Question` variable at all? If you could call derived-class methods on a base class variable, it would not be a base class variable.

Comment: Thanks for the response but you can call derived class methods on a base class variable. e.g. if Question implemented the requested (no-args) method then it would be allowed. Polymorphism would kick in. Furthermore, at runtime the Blue class implementation would kick in. So my question is what would be so bad about the Compiler treating b as a Blue since it is a Blue and the compiler knows it's a Blue.

Comment: The point of polymorphism is that having the variable of type `Question` is a way of treating the instance like a `Question` and not needing to know about what specific implementation it is. If you don't want to treat your object like a `Question`, then you don't want to use polymorphism, so don't declare your variable to be of type `Question`.

Comment: Thank you, I think I get it now. So if say an Animal has methods sleep and eat and it's child Dog has a method bark. Then if the Dog is being treated as an Animal then it should not be allowed to bark? Sorry for the long winded question.